# Jquery Confirmation Box poisition issue inside iframe

Tags: jquery

I made a small wall script on a page in which if we remove any post then a confirmation box appears and yes or no option.

If I open this page direct then confirmation box

I am using this jquery plugin

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

but when I add my page inside an iframe then my alert confirmation box displays in the middle of page all time even I click on any wall post delete link

I want to fix that if I use this jQuery plugin confirmation box inside an iframe then it will appear in the correct place.

I have tried the following code for top

```
var top = (($(window).height() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerHeight() / 2)) + $.alerts.verticalOffset;

var left = (($(window).width() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerWidth() / 2)) + $.alerts.horizontalOffset;
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide a bit more context, and maybe a http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code?

Comment: hello. i can share you my site id pwd to test but can not share the pwd here there u can see exact issue

Comment: basicly i feel issue is javascript code var top = (($(window).height() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerHeight() / 2)) + $.alerts.verticalOffset; coz i am using in iframe and its working for full window

Comment: I tried this which worked: http://jsfiddle.net/hKnEJ/. Note that the four code boxes in JSFiddle actually are iFrames, so it should be comparable to your problem.

Comment: did u made any changes? the problem is i am using a small wall script and many posts share there so all post have delete button when user click on delete then confirmation box appear and that not working proper. here u use only 1 box so 1 is appear fine. if u do not mind can i give u a demo user id pwd and u can check live

Comment: actualy my project got stuck here and i am not able to move fwd and already 5 days past i am not able to solve this issue. i request if u can check the live and get idea abt my issue

Comment: I don't want access to your live environment. But make a jsfiddle or post the code including context and you'll likely get the help you need from the SO community.

Comment: but the error coming in live site php and jquery code how i can put it in jsfiddle. and am not sharing ftp access. no just a demo user id pwd there you can check the error instantly and better and easy to understand my issue. i request coz i am stuck in this form almost a month:(